# Will webViewLink generated for a file in appdata folder work?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have stored a pdf file to appDataFolder which is application specific, using the get call I am trying to get the file url using 'webViewLink, webContentLink'. But opening the links does not show anything but using alt=media I was able to get the buffer and write it to a file.

```
const test = await drive.files.get({
       fileId: fileId,
       fields: 'webViewLink, webContentLink',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe my misunderstanding but if you want to get download link you
need function like this

```
    public function getWebViewLinkByFileId($file_id)
   {
       try {
           $service = $this->getService();
           $response = $service->files->get($file_id, array(
               'fields' => 'webViewLink'));
           $downloadLink = $response->webViewLink;
           return $downloadLink;
       } catch (Exception $e) {
           throw $e;
       }
   }
```

This is php code and for webViewLink you need to config permissions

```
               $service->getClient()->setUseBatch(true);
               $batch = $service->createBatch();
               $userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
                   'type' => 'anyone',
                   'role' => 'reader',
               ));
               $request = $service->permissions->create(
                   $fileId, $userPermission, array('fields' => 'id'));
               $batch->add($request, 'anyone');
               $results = $batch->execute();
```